# Update an application running in a compute instance on Azure

Tags: java, scala, azure, playframework

I have a successfully deployed a web application running Scala with the Play! Framework on a compute instance of Windows Azure. Everything works pretty well. For doing this I used the Eclipse plugin to deploy the application.

My question is how to handle the lifecycle of the application? When I want to update my application, how should I go about it? Create a new staging instance, deploy it from Eclipse and then do the switch? This sounds very cumbersome and slow, especially for small patches / improvements. Or is there a way to upload only the code?

Thank you!

Comment: Any way of managing your deployed app without windows ?

Comment: From console. Also take a look at JRebel.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend uploading to staging, test using the staging URL and then swap the VIP.  Once you are happy, delete the old deployment (now in staging).  The VIP swap offers user stability, and maintains the user's session until all the sessions are drained.